# assigning physics.setGravity a different value

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-engine, physics

```
--***************************************************

-- drawButtons() --> 

--***************************************************

local flyPlane = function(event)

    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
        print("began")
        physics.setGravity( 0, -10 )
    elseif event.phase == "ended" and gameIsActive == true then
        print("ended")
        physics.setGravity( 0, 7 )
        inBound = true
    elseif event.phase == "moved" and gameIsActive == true then
        -- do nothing
    end

end

--***************************************************

-- keepPlaneInBound() --> 

--***************************************************

local keepPlaneInBound = function()
    -- print("checking")
    if paperPlane.y <= paperPlane.height + 10 and gameIsActive == true and inBound == true then
        inBound = false
        paperPlane.y = paperPlane.height + 12
    end

    if paperPlane.y > display.contentHeight - paperPlane.height - scale.height and gameIsActive == true then
        paperPlane.y = display.contentHeight - paperPlane.height - scale.height
    end

end
```

The function flyPlane is set on "touch" eventlistner and keepPlaneInBound has been set to "enterframe" eventlistner. What i want to achieve is that when the plane exceeds the upper bound limit. Its previous physcis.setGravity value to be completely removed and the new value to be assigned to it when the user lifts the finger (when event = "ended").
What happens odd is that it does not accept the new physics.setGravity() value. In case i use physics.pause() and then assign it the new gravity value. On physics.start it first completes the part of the previous setGravity value hence moving it upwards again.. :/

Comment: There is a priori nothing wrong with your gravity code, not sure about the bounds checking because it looks like there is an extra "end" in `keepPlaneInBound` that will cause syntax error. So please correct that and also edit your question to show the code where you register event callbacks, that is likely where the error is.

Comment: @Schollii. hi, thanks for helping me out. The "end" you are talking about was added by mistake here. I've eidited the code. Now the code is exactly how it looks in my notepad++.

Comment: OK but as I mentioned, I can't see anything wrong with your code, I have even tried changing gravity in a test app and it works fine, so the problem is with code you don't show. Please show your addEventListener calls, and whatever other code you use to call the two functions. "function flyPlane is set on "touch" "enterframe" eventlistner" does not make sense, need to see the code.

Comment: sore, @Schollii . I agree with you I've made some serious mistakes in the description of the problem. It is solved now. I have posted what i did to get rid of it. Thanks, anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have "flyPlane" as the callback in "enterFrame". You should have something like this:

```
local function flyPlane(event) 
   your_code()
end

local function keepPlaneInBound(event)
   your_code()
end

paperPlane:addEventListener("touch", flyPlane)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", keepPlaneInBound)
```

That is all you need. (Given that your game logic is correct)

Comment: hi Adam, thanks for the help. Yes, that took me somwhere near the solution. But the main problem still lies there. The value of gravity that i want to assign to the paperPlane object when the player lifts up his finger from the screen. The object just keeps itself stick with the previously assigned value of gravity(assigned at the "began" event).

Comment: The only reason that is even possible is if the gameIsActive boolean is evaluated to false. -- and by the way, you dont have to do 
"if boolean == true then", you can just say "if boolean then"

Answer (score 0):

folks. i got what i was looking for. The technique to remove the force applying onto the physics body completely in order to assign it a new gravity value is to simply change its bodyType to a different type and then assigning back the required bodyType again to the object. This way the effect of the previous gravity value on your physics object gets completely removed.This is what i did. It surely worked for me.

```
-- drawButtons() --> 

--***************************************************

local flyPlane = function(event)

    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
        print("began")
        -- paperPlane.bodyType = "dynamic"
        physics.setGravity( 0, -10 )
        -- physics.start()
    elseif event.phase == "ended" and gameIsActive == true then
        print("ended")
        -- paperPlane.bodyType = "dynamic"
        physics.setGravity( 0, 7 )
        -- physics.start()
    elseif event.phase == "moved" and gameIsActive == true then
    end

end

--***************************************************

-- keepPlaneInBound() --> 

--***************************************************

local keepPlaneInBound = function()
    -- print("checking")
    if paperPlane.y <= paperPlane.height + 10 and gameIsActive == true then
        print("Out of Bound -y:   ", paperPlane.bodyType)
        physics.pause()
        paperPlane.bodyType = "static"
        paperPlane.y = paperPlane.height + 11
    elseif paperPlane.y > display.contentHeight - paperPlane.height - scale.height and gameIsActive == true then
        print("Out of Bound +y:   ", paperPlane.bodyType)
        physics.pause()
        paperPlane.bodyType = "static"
        paperPlane.y = display.contentHeight - paperPlane.height - scale.height - 1
    else 
        print("In Bound:    ", paperPlane.bodyType)
        paperPlane.bodyType = "dynamic"
        physics.start()
    end

end
```

Comment: That can't be it because setGravity works immediately (ie as soon as the event handler returns) on all bodies, without pausing physics (I've verified). And it does not make sense that you would have to change every physics body type (at all) in order for new gravity to take effect. It's a hack, something else was wrong.